# dia python extensions - can you make code that does things based on the diagrams?

Tags: python, workflow, diagram, dia

While creating some diagrams in Dia using the bpmn sheet I noticed that there's a capability for using python extensions on Dia.  They have some examples on their site about doing so.

[Dia Project](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)

What I haven't seen yet (and I'm wondering about) is whether you can generate something code, yaml or xml based on a diagram?  For example say you create a workflow process diagram - is there a way you could examine it in Python and then write some logic in there to produce a representation of the workflow that could be used to drive a workflow engine perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [`codegen.py`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia/-/blob/master/plug-ins/python/codegen.py) in [their plug-in](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Python) directory of the project.

> Another 'export filter' is codegen.py, which converts a diagram made
> with objects from Dia's UML sheet into code in a user-selectable
> programming language (at one time, Python, C++, Pascal, and Java were
> supported...